# Display 1000 comma separator in view MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I do have below MVC view element and I am trying to display data in 1000 separator without decimal.I tried applying "{0:C0}","{0:N0}"  (Option 1) in data annotation so that when data is pulled from database and displayed in view data annotation will be applied.it didn't work

E.g: 1000000 => 1,000,000

Option 1

```
[Display(Name = "Services", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Labels))]
            [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")]
            public int? Services { get; set; }
```

As a Option 2 , I tried below code snippet this displays the pulled data in the format 1,000,000 but in the post method the field value is always null. Any inputs where data can be displayed in format of 1,000,000 but when it comes to post back end it should still pass value as 1000000.

Option 2

```
<div class="notified-option-value cell border-top border-right" id=@("value-container" + i)>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OptionsEditViewModel.AddCoverageBBR[k].AddCoverage.Services, "{0:C0}", new { id = "limit-of-coverage-value" + i, @class = "option-value cell" })
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for situations like this.

1. Handle the formatting (1000 -> 1,000) and parsing (1,000 -> 1000) in JavaScript,

set the input to type **text** and format the content using the input events like `onblur`, `onchange` or `onkeyup`, there are some jQuery libraries that can handle this.

2. make the model field as string, so when you send something like `1,000,000` will get accepted (and not null) and you handle it in the C# code, using properties with getters and setters may help in these cases.